# Creating dart server in global network

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, networking, server

I am trying to create a dart/flutter application that is capable of sending and receiving data with sockets over the internet (WAN), without an intermediary, peer-to-peer.

I may have managed to create this on the local network (LAN), through the wifi I can transfer data, but how to transfer data on the global network?
It seems to me that I need to open a port, but how can I do this on dart? Or is there another way.

Briefly - Chat between 2 directly connected users wherever they are.
I tried to connect to an external IP address, but it does not work, I searched and asked people, but they do not know.

Comment: Do the computers your servers are running on have globally routable IP addresses?  Do your servers have a way of knowing (or finding out) each other's IP addresses?  They will need that in order to communicate.  Also, will either (or both) of your servers be behind NAT or a firewall?  If so, they will need to some way to get their packets past those filters.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner
I want to make a mobile application for communicating with a direct connection, without servers, and if you meant a server on a mobile device, what does globally routable IP addresses mean?
Addresses will be recognized manually, you just need to find a way to show your address, but that's another question.
I don’t know about NAT.
I'm not good at this.

Comment: Afaik most mobile devices are not configured to be directly accessible to incoming packets from the internet, as that would open them up to hacking and denial-of-service attempts.  The pattern most services use is to have each device communicate with a server, and the server forwards data from one device to another as necessary.

Comment: Globally reputable IP address is one that can be used to access the same device from anywhere (as opposed to an address that is only meaningful in a given local context; eg 127.0.0.1 which refers to whatever machine the calling program is currently running on; or eg 10.0.0.1 which refers to a computer on the local LAN and doesn’t mean anything outside of a particular LAN)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, It means can't connect directly from one device to another? If I know the globally routable IP address.
How do other applications that allow direct connections work?
Maybe need a virtual network or something like that?

Comment: The pattern most services use is to have each device communicate with a server, and the server forwards data from one device to another as necessary.   (some applications like Skype use a technique called "hole punching" to enable direct communication between devices, but that technique doesn't always work, and still requires a server to bootstrap the process). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, The initial loading of the process will be carried out in the firebase or other ways to find out the external address.
Thanks for the answer about the hole punching technique, what does it mean "doesn't always work"? And exist realizations for dart?

Comment: Hole-punching relies on particular behavior-patterns on the part of the NAT/firewalls at the client sites (e.g. it might depend on the NAT allowing incoming packets from a given IP address if the client computer has rescently sent outgoing packets to that same IP address).  However, NAT packet-filter behavior isn't standardized, so there's no guarantee the client's firewall will actually behave as desired, so it's generally necessary to have a fallback mode (e.g. where all data is routed through the server) to handle those cases.  I don't know anything about dart so I can't speak to that.